# Unable to loadDatabase with lokiJs

Tags: lokijs

I have trying to create a database with a collection added to this database and the changes saved to a IndexedDB.

Below is my code

1. Two controllers SaveController and LoadController.

myApp.controller('SaveController', ['$scope', 'Loki', function ($scope, Loki) {

```
// SAVE : will save App/Key/Val as 'finance'/'test'/{serializedDb}
// if appContect ('finance' in this example) is omitted, 'loki' will be used
var idbAdapter = new LokiIndexedAdapter('finance');

var db = new loki('ProjectDb', { adapter: idbAdapter });

var coll = db.addCollection('SampleCollection');
coll.insert({ SampleId: 'Sample text.....' });

db.saveDatabase();  // could pass callback if needed for async complete
```

}]);

and then in my LoadController i use the

myApp.controller('LoadController', ['$scope', 'Loki', function ($scope, Loki) {

```
var idbAdapter = new LokiIndexedAdapter('finance');

var db = new loki('ProjectDb', { adapter: idbAdapter, autoload: true });
db.loadDatabase({}, function (result) {
    console.log(result);
});

alert(db.getCollection("SampleCollection"));
```

}]);

I get a null when i alert "alert(db.getCollection("SampleCollection"));" . It never enters the call back of the "loadDatabase" method.

Is there something that i am missing ?

IndexedDB in Browser

[image: IndexedDB]

Here the page html

[image: Page HTML]

[image: lokijs script controller]

***Edit for default localstorage implementation***

I use the default implementation for loki js and i try to load the offline db is shows result as null every time even though the db exist

```
var offlineDb = new loki('DbOfflineNew');
    offlineDb.loadDatabase({},function (result) {
        console.log(result);
        if (result == null) {
            alert('loading for first time..');
        }
        else {
            alert('existing load..');
        }
    });
```

Every time the alert "loading for first time.. " is fired.. Any thing i am missing here..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically all your logic needs to be in the loadDatabase callback. If you try to `console.log` the collection before it's loaded it will be null. Many people fall in this trap.

In other words:

```
myApp.controller('LoadController', ['$scope', 'Loki', function ($scope, Loki) {

var idbAdapter = new LokiIndexedAdapter('finance');

var db = new loki('ProjectDb', { adapter: idbAdapter, autoload: true });
db.loadDatabase({}, function (result) {
    console.log(result);
    // put your log call here.
    alert(db.getCollection("SampleCollection"));
});
}]);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This would be the canonical answer ;)

Comment: Hi Joe, I have edited my question this time to load database for default loki js implementation and everytime the value in the callback for loadDatabase method comes with a null value ?

Comment: Got it to working checked once again on the http://lokijs.org/#/docs#load site found that the result is never returned for default local storage implementation . Thanks